# Tirar barra de título da janela tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

Boa noite, a QUESTÃO é: como tiro a barra de título da janela tk sem torná-la segundo plano, que é o que overrideredirect(True) faz?

Com várias pesquisas, vi que esta linha poderia ajudar:

```
root.wm_attributes('-type', 'splash')
```

Mas o parâmetro "-type" não é reconhecido.

O código abaixo por exemplo, faz o prometido com o overrideredirect(True)

```
from tkinter import *
Root = Tk()
Root.overrideredirect(True)
Root.mainloop()
```

Mas se nota que o ícone da janela nem aparece na barra de tarefas do windows, ou seja, não dá nem pra minimizar.

Alguma solução pra isso?

Comment: Pelo que eu pesquisei rapidamente, a opção "type" funciona apenas em Linux (tem opções específicas para Mac, Linux e Windows). Você gostaria de criar uma janela sem barra de título para evitar que alguém feche a janela clicando no X? Ou pra evitar que seja maximizada? Redimensionada? Se for, existem alternativas mais simples. Explica um pouco mais qual seu objetivo.

Comment: @BrunoOliveira Uma janela sem barra de título para poder personalizá-la, mas sem ocultar ela da barra de tarefas.

Answer (score -2):

Juega con estas opciones

```
def override(event):
    hwnd = win32gui.GetParent(root.winfo_id())
    style= win32api.GetWindowLong(hwnd, win32con.GWL_STYLE)
    style&= ~win32con.WS_MINIMIZEBOX
    style&= ~win32con.WS_MAXIMIZEBOX
    style&= ~win32con.WS_SYSMENU
    style&= ~win32con.WS_CAPTION
    style&= ~win32con.WS_SIZEBOX
    valid= win32api.SetWindowLong(hwnd, win32con.GWL_STYLE, style)
    root.bind('<Map>', None)
```

ejemplo:

```
import win32con
import win32api
import win32gui
import tkinter as tk
            
def override(event):
    hwnd = win32gui.GetParent(root.winfo_id())
    style= win32api.GetWindowLong(hwnd, win32con.GWL_STYLE)
    style&= ~win32con.WS_MINIMIZEBOX
    style&= ~win32con.WS_MAXIMIZEBOX
    style&= ~win32con.WS_SYSMENU
    style&= ~win32con.WS_CAPTION
    style&= ~win32con.WS_SIZEBOX
    valid= win32api.SetWindowLong(hwnd, win32con.GWL_STYLE, style)
    root.bind('<Map>', None)
root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('800x600')
root.bind('<Map>', override)
root.mainloop()
```